# Homotopy group of $O(p,q)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homotopy-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

I am interested in knowing the homotopy group of $O(p,q)$ as [the orthogonal group of indefinite quadratic form over the reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group#Of_indefinite_quadratic_form_over_the_reals).

Here $O(p,q)$ is defined as
$$
O(p,q) ={O}(p,q; \mathbb{R}) = \left\{Q \in \operatorname{GL}(p+q, \mathbb{R}) \mid Q^\mathsf{T}I_{p,q} Q = Q I_{p,q} Q^\mathsf{T} = I_{p,q}\right\}
$$
with the field $F=\mathbb{R}$.
Here
$$
I_{p,q}
\equiv
\begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 &        & \\
        & \ddots & \\
        &        & 1
  \end{pmatrix}_{p \times p} & 0 \\
  0 & \begin{pmatrix}
    - 1 &        & \\
          & \ddots & \\
          &        & -1
  \end{pmatrix}_{q \times q}\\
\end{bmatrix} $$

So

1. **what is the homotopy group: $\pi_d(O(1,d-1))=?$**
2. what is the homotopy group: $\pi_d(O(p,q))=?$

If you can answer $\pi_d(O(1,d-1))$, then it is enough to post your thoughts as an answer. I do appreciate it.

I am particularly interested in $\pi_0(O(1,d-1))$, $\pi_1(O(1,d-1))$, and
$\pi_2(O(1,d-1))$, and $d=0,\dots,5$.

[The $\pi_2(G)=0$ for Lie group $G$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/8957/27004). I suppose it still holds for $G$ is a noncompact nonabelian Lie group.

See also useful info here [Homotopy groups O(N) and SO(N): $\pi_m(O(N))$ v.s. $\pi_m(SO(N))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2455331/79069).

Comment: Hint: $O(p,q)$ is homotopy equivalent to $O(p)\times O(q)$.

Comment: Thanks +1, There is also this question but no answer https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2166682/79069 on Homotopy between (,) and ()×()

Comment: Since you're asking about homotopy groups, we really only care about the identity components $SO^+(p, q)$ and $SO(p)\times SO(q)$. For the proof of homotopy equivalence, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/284658) outlines a construction of a deformation retract $SO^+(p, q)\to SO(p)\times SO(q)$. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3487830) constructs a fibration with $SO(p)\times SO(q)$ as the fiber, $SO^+(p,q)$ as the total space, and a contractible base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted by the comments and links therein, we have
$$
\pi_d((,))=\pi_d((p) \times O(q))=\pi_d((p)) \times \pi_d(O(q)).
$$
Then $$\pi_0((p))=\mathbb{Z}/2,$$
$$\pi_{d>1}((p))=\pi_{d>1}(S(p)).$$

Thus to give some example, say $(3,1)$,
$$
\pi_0((3,1))=\pi_0((3)) \times \pi_0(O(1))=(\mathbb{Z}/2)^2.
$$
$$
\pi_1((3,1))=\pi_1((3)) \times \pi_1(O(1))=\mathbb{Z}/2.
$$
$$
\pi_2((3,1))=\pi_2((3)) \times \pi_2(O(1))=0.
$$
$$
\pi_3((3,1))=\pi_3((3)) \times \pi_3(O(1))=\mathbb{Z}.
$$
$$
\pi_4((3,1))=\pi_4((3)) \times \pi_4(O(1))=\mathbb{Z}/2.
$$
$$
\pi_5((3,1))=\pi_5((3)) \times \pi_5(O(1))=\mathbb{Z}/2.
$$
$$
\pi_6((3,1))=\pi_6((3)) \times \pi_6(O(1))=\mathbb{Z}/12.
$$